# Simple PHP Shopping Cart without SQL

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple PHP shopping cart with prices, products, registration, and a checkout area. I've searched Google for tutorials but all of them incorporate SQL which is not within my skill set yet. Anyone have any examples or other tutorial resources you could refer to a PHP novice?

Again just trying to create simple PHP shopping cart (no SQL) using arrays for products, functions for various program tasks, form validation, cookies/sessions for cart continuity, template files, and confirmation/receipt emails.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why don't you learn SQL instead? It is, in fact, quite easier than writing a usable shopping cart (even a simple one) without a DB.

Comment: What sad dude said. Don't implement a solution based on lack of skillset, either learn it yourself or hire a consultant to get you started. You may also want to look into open source ecommerce solutions.

Comment: Go learn SQL and use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of criticizing, why not just help? Hypocritical, but whatever.
Please keep in mind, without an SQL database, you cannot "register", but you can have premade usernames and passwords

So, lets create your pseudo sql database with php.

We need a table to store usernames and passwords for your login thing.

```
<?php
    //name this "users.php"
    //Keep in mind, this method does not secure your passwords... in fact, their so visible that you shouldn't ever use this method to store passwords. EVER. i'm just using to because i'm cool like that.
    //we'll name this "accounts", and make it a 2D array
    $accounts = array (
        array("username" => "username 1", "password" => "my password!"),
        array("username" => "username 2", "password" => "weeeeeee"),
        array("username" => "username 3", "password" => "aidsfijasjdfiawe"),
        array("username" => "rex", "password" => "asdfajweiogjr"),
        array("username" => "Kodlee Yin", "password" => "ghreoghrueagre")
    );
    //you get the point. Username goes into username, password into password. Create more for more users etc.
?>
```

Now we need a table to store products

```
<?php
    //name this "products.php"
    $products = array (
        array("name" => "Whoop-ass", "price" => "9.99", "description" => "Its a can of whoop-ass"),
        array("name" => "Mouse", "price" => "54.95", "description" => "No, it's not real. It's a gaming mouse. 9200 DPI"),
        array("name" => "iPad", "price" => "Too expensive", "description" => "Something you never need, but something you want"),
        array("name" => "Stack Overflow", "price" => "9001.00", "description" => "The best website in the world."),
        array("name" => "Generic item 5", "price" => "4.99", "description" => "It says 4.99, but deep in your heart, you know its really 5 dollars.")
    );
?>
```

So we have our products "table" and our accounts "table".
Now here is the harder part which is create the system that takes all this information, displays it, allows a login and logout, and keeps track of the items you have in the cart.

```
<?php
    //name this file "index.php"

    //now keep in mind. I'm not going to fancy this up, so it's gonna look pretty ugly.
    //i'm also going to use javascript and jQuery (a javascript library) because I love the two. :)

    //lets name and start a session
    session_name("rexthing");
    session_start();

    //this string is arbitrary, but i like it for debugging
    $errorqueue = '';

    //we need to add our login details and products!
    include("users.php");
    include("products.php");

    //now in a normal php application of logging in or handling of login requests, i don't suggest doing this, but this is quick and easy(ish)
    $action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action']: ""; //Ternary operator asking if there is an inputted action
    switch($action)
    {
        case "login":
            if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) //check if we're already logged in
            {
                $errorqueue['Login'] = "We've already logged in!";
            } else {
                $errorqueue['login'] = "Invalid username/password";
                $username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username']: ""; //check if there is a username supplied, if not then leave it blank
                $password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password']: ""; //check for password
                foreach($accounts as $value) //this is our login attempt
                {
                    if(($username == $value['username']) && ($password == $value['password']))
                    {
                        //please please please, never ever use this as a real login validation method!!! I'm just using it because i'm doing this quickly!
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        $_SESSION['cart'] = ''; //this is our cart for the user this session
                        unset($errorqueue['login']);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case "logout":
            session_unset(); //deletes all session variables/cookies
            break;
        case "additem":
            //this is a quick and dirty way to make a cart! plz if you're ever going to make a cart... don't do this!
            $itemid = (isset($_GET['itemid'])) ? $_GET['itemid']: "";
            if($itemid != "")
            {
                if($_SESSION['cart'] == "")
                {
                    $_SESSION['cart'] = array($products[$itemid]);
                } else {
                    array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $products[$itemid]);
                }
            }
            break;
        case "clearcart":
            $_SESSION['cart'] = "";
            break;
    }

    //we can now dynamically load our data knowing if we're logged in or not.
    //I'll even throw in some neat little effects because i'm bored
    echo <<<DISP
    <html>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <head>
            <title>Rex's awesome thing</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('.button').mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).animate({opacity:1},200);
                    })
                    .mouseleave(function() {
                        $(this).animate({opacity:.6},200);
                    });
                    $('#login_button').click(function() {
                        $('#login_form').submit();
                    });
                    $('.disp_item').click(function() {
                        var itemid = $(this).attr("id");
                        var location = "index.php?action=additem&itemid="+itemid;
                        window.location.href = location;
                    });
                    $('.disp_item').mouseover(function() {
                        $(this).css("background-color","#CCC");
                    })
                    .mouseleave(function() {
                        $(this).css("background-color","transparent");
                    });
                    $('#clearcart').click(function() {
                        window.location.href= "index.php?action=clearcart";
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    background-color:#000;
                    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
                    -khtml-user-select: none;
                    -webkit-user-select: none;
                    user-select: none;
                    min-width:1000px;
                }
                #wrapper {
                    position:absolute;
                    top:10px;
                    right:50px;
                    left:50px;
                    min-height:500px;
                    background-color:#333;
                    border-radius: 15px;
                    padding: 10px 20px;
                }
                .button {
                    display:inline-block;
                    padding: 2px 20px;
                    background-color:#FFF;
                    border: 1px solid #999;
                    opacity:.6;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    border-radius:7px;
                }
                #logout {
                    color:#FFF;
                }
                .lololol {
                    display:inline-block;
                    width:150px;
                }
                .di_desc {
                    width:600px !important;
                }
                .disp_item {
                    cursor:pointer;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
DISP;
//the "DISP;" line must be on the far left with nothing after it. don't ask why. It just must.


        //now check to see if we're logged in or not
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) //now i'm using the true/false return of the "isset" function to determine if we've set (logged in) this variable
        {
            //yes we're logged in! lets show some stuff!
            $dUsername = $_SESSION['username'];

            echo <<<DISP
            Welcome $dUsername!<br />
            It's nice to see you back! <br />
            Click <a href="index.php?action=logout" id="logout">here</a> to logout!<br />
            <br />
DISP;
//this disp, same as above
            //lets display the stuff we have in our cart already
            echo "Stuff we have in our cart:<br />\n";
            $cart_total = 0;
            if($_SESSION['cart'] != '') {
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value)
            {
                $cart_total = $cart_total + $value['price'];
                $name = $value['name'];
                $price = $value['price'];
                $desc = $value['description'];
                echo <<<DISP
                <div class="ahahahaha">
                    <span class="di_name lololol">$name</span>
                    <span class="di_price lololol">\$$price</span>
                    <span class="di_desc lololol">$desc</span>
                </div>
DISP;
            } }
            echo "Cart total: $".$cart_total;
            echo '<br /><span class="button" id="clearcart">Clear Cart</span>';
            echo "<br /> <br/>\n"; //some space
            //lets display stuff not in our cart
            echo "Click an item to add it to your cart:<br />\n";
            foreach($products as $key => $value)
            {
                $name = $value['name'];
                $price = $value['price'];
                $desc = $value['description'];
                echo <<<DISP
                <div id="$key" class="disp_item">
                    <span class="di_name lololol">$name</span>
                    <span class="di_price lololol">\$$price</span>
                    <span class="di_desc lololol">$desc</span>
                </div>
DISP;
//you know the drill...
            }
        } else { //isset if
            //no we're not logged in, show our login form
            echo <<<HAHA
            <form method="post" action="index.php?action=login" id="login_form">
            Username:<br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="login_username" /><br />
            <br />
            Password:<br />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="login_password" /><br />
            <br />
            </form>
            <span class="button" id="login_button">Login</span>
HAHA;
//the "HAHA;" line must be on the far left.
        } //isset if

        //show our errors
        echo "<br /> <br />\n";
        if($errorqueue != "") {
        foreach($errorqueue as $key => $value)
        {
            echo $key . " error: " . $value . "! <br />\n";
        }}
        echo <<<FINI
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
FINI;
?>
```

If you don't have a server that can parse the PHP, I've placed this on my server (as i needed to test it before giving it) avaiable here:
[Your SQL-less shopping cart](http://kodleeshare.net/rex/)

Comment: You're amazing Kodlee Yin! Wow thank you so much for your help. I'll be sitting down and working through your code today to try and incorporate it to what I've already started. Fortunately I have an internal server/programming environment setup to parse the PHP with XAMPP/Aptana, but thank you for hosting the example on your server!! In case I do have any problems I'll be sure to write to your e-mail address. Thanks again for your very generous help!!!

Answer (score 2):

From your question it seems as if you have a fundamental misunderstanding for what SQL is and what PHP arrays provide.

The key word here is really **"persistence"**.  How do you want the data about your customers and the transactions to be saved?  You cannot simply populate a PHP array and expect this data to stick around when you need it later.  You must *persist* this data to a disk in some fashion.  There is simply no getting around this fact.

There are some different options when it comes to persisting data onto a disk.

**File System**

http://php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php

PHP provides a variety of functions to work with the file system.  You could create a shopping cart that uses flat, text files as the means of persistence.  Chances are if you go this route you'll have more problems implementing this than if you had simply learned SQL.

**NoSQL databases**

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php

PHP supports document databases like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) that don't use SQL for interaction and storage.  Ultimately you will still have to likely learn how to access this database as well, although it is very much like JavaScript.

**SQL databases**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

And of course PHP provides traditional SQL database support.

---

Either way you will have to *learn* something new, there is simply no way around it.  The real question is what do you value learning the most?  I would definitely push you towards learning SQL.  It will become invaluable to you and once you learn how to use a database to store data it will ultimately make your development projects a lot easier.

Comment: I totally agree with all of you, and SQL is the next course/topic I will be learning. But for the sake of my current PHP project I have to create the above-mentioned shopping cart using PHP only. Clearly I'm having a hard time figuring this out, and so I was hoping I could find some alternative tutorials since all I found on Google involved PHP/MySQL shopping carts. If anyone has any PHP only shopping cart references that would be much appreciated.

Comment: And thank you all for taking the time to reply to my question! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling found:
http://www.webforcecart.com/

In most basic shopping cart examples the SQL could probably be converted into arrays kept in global or session variables. Probably not the best way to make an actual shopping cart, but might be worth it for fun?

I think a basic cart to see if you can have a cart and add/remove products it might be ok, but once you start wanting user registration/adding/editing/removing products etc., using a database will help make life easier.

Comment: Thanks for the reference a1210!