# Add items to a cart from an array

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a php driven shopping cart as part of a task.
All products are currently stored in an array (I'm aware they would realistically be stored in a database, however for this task it isn't required)

I would like to know if its possible to add items to a cart from clicking a link, upon clicking proceed, it would take the user to a summary screen, displaying the cost of each item (value displayed from the array) and total cost of all items.

I am also looking to include a promotion code input box, is it possible to calculate and display a discount on button click, E.G "Update"

So far, I only have the products displayed in a table which is ok, the cart section is confusing me at the moment as well as the discount section.

```
<?php
$Item1 = array('SKU'=>test1, 'name'=>ProductTest1, 'Price'=>10.00);
$Item2 = array('SKU'=>test2, 'name'=>ProductTest2, 'Price'=>11.00);
$Item3 = array('SKU'=>test3, 'name'=>ProductTest3, 'Price'=>12.00);

?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
<table>
<tr>
<th>SKU</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $Item1[SKU]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $Item1[name]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo '£'. number_format($Item1[Price],2); ?></td>
<td><a href=#>Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $Item2[SKU]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $Item2[name]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo '£'. number_format($Item2[Price],2); ?></td>
<td><a href=#>Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $Item3[SKU]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $Item3[name]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo '£'. number_format($Item3[Price],2); ?></td>
<td><a href=#>Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input id="Proceed" type="Submit" value="Proceed">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? It sounds like you're asking for a great deal of code to be written for you.

Comment: Your question is very general, it can't be answered. Take into account that SO is not a programming service. There are lot of programming tutorials on Internet that will show the way to achieve what you are looking for. I will help you with the following: you will need `$_SESSION`, and AJAX calls (take a look to jQuery)

Comment: We help in problems. no body will do your work

Comment: I don't expect the code to be laid out in front of me, I was wondering if its possible to temporarily store the items in php to be displayed upon clicking proceed.
And if its also possible to update a total value at the click of a button, calling a discount function either from a database or text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first this is not good way to use the array like this. Try this:

```
<?php
$products = array(
    array('SKU'=>test1, 'name'=>ProductTest1, 'Price'=>10.00),
    array('SKU'=>test2, 'name'=>ProductTest2, 'Price'=>11.00),
    array('SKU'=>test3, 'name'=>ProductTest3, 'Price'=>12.00),
);

?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
<table>
<tr>
<th>SKU</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($products as $key => $product): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $product['SKU']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo '£'. number_format($product['Price'],2); ?></td>
<td><a href="#">Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
</table>
<input id="Proceed" type="Submit" value="Proceed">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now how to solve the cart. You have to use something persistent. The session will be easiest:

```
<?php
session_start();
$products = array(
    array('SKU'=>test1, 'name'=>ProductTest1, 'Price'=>10.00),
    array('SKU'=>test2, 'name'=>ProductTest2, 'Price'=>11.00),
    array('SKU'=>test3, 'name'=>ProductTest3, 'Price'=>12.00),
);

if (isset($_GET['action'] && $_GET['action'] === 'addToCart') {
   if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']) $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
   $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_GET['product'];
}

?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])): ?>
<ul id="cart">
<?php foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product): ?>
   <li><?= $products[$product]['name'] ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<table>
<tr>
<th>SKU</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($products as $key => $product): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $product['SKU']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo '£'. number_format($product['Price'],2); ?></td>
<td><a href="?action=addToCart&product=<?php echo $key ?>">Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
</table>
<input id="Proceed" type="Submit" value="Proceed">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work. Just adapting your code.

Comment: Oh Wow, thankyou so much!
As i'm sifting through the additional code, i've just added the foreach loop, and a product, the first one in the list is SKU test3, is there any way to display test1 first then test2, test3?

Comment: You can sort the array by one of the function the php offers. For example `usort` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php, look to the documentation. By this you can specifiy every order you wish.

Comment: Will this allow me to echo out each array?
Thats the issue at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Your first port of call will be to look into sessions (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Your Add to Cart link will go through to a different PHP page, so it might be addtocart.php

Each Add to Cart link will pass through the SKU/Product ID, so the link for each will have a unique GET parameter - I.E. addtocart.php?sku=test1 - That way you know which Product you're adding to cart.

I'd read through a couple of tutorials from Google, like http://jameshamilton.eu/content/simple-php-shopping-cart-tutorial?PHPSESSID=99d373741727e3010a32319f1ebed001

If you're still having trouble, breakdown your question into specific points and I'm sure someone will help out.

See [Simple PHP Shopping Cart without SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597556/simple-php-shopping-cart-without-sql) for creating a shopping cart without a database.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your sensible answer!
Just out of curiosity, would it be considered improper for the cart to appear on the same page as the products, or can php not calculate on the fly?

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand, but I would advise having the cart on a different page to the products. Once you've added the item to the cart, you can always redirect back to the page that you were just on with a header redirect (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)